# Can't see DropZoneJS Tooltip when selected file has an error

Tags: html, css, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am working with DropZoneJS and am attempting to test when a user selects a file type that is not allowed.  Everything seems to be working, but the tooltip displaying the error for the file is cut off and not visible.  Here is my DropZone declaration:

```
           <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="dZAvatar" class="dropzone dzFormat">
                        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                            Pick a file to use as your avatar.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript code (not sure if this matters  for this question, but here it is anyway):

```
            $("#dZAvatar").dropzone({
                url: "handlers/setavatarfile.ashx",
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
                maxFilesize: 2,
                maxFiles: 1,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                success: function (file, response) {
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                    if (response.Success = true)
                        $("#toastAvatarOK").toast('show');
                    else {
                        $('#spnAvatarErr').html(response.Message);
                        $("#toastAvatarFail").toast('show');
                    }
                },
                error: function (file, response) {
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
                    $('#spnAvatarErr').html('Unable to process this file.');
                    $("#toastAvatarFail").toast('show');
                }
            });
```

And here's the only CSS I have for the DropZone code.  It is only meant to limit the size of the DropZone and ensure it is centered:

```
.dzFormat {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here's the screenshot showing the cut-off tooltip when the user selects an incorrect file type:
[image: Screenshot showing tooltip is cut off and not visible]

Any help on what I'm doing wrong here would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey there! It would be better if you can show a demo of the error using the Dropzone library here or through Codesandbox. It can also help you to get a quick or better answer.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can try using something like this: https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/jyxNqL